# PHP Mail Don't Show "To" in "To" Header

Tags: php, email, mime, cpanel

I want to make an email forwarder similar to cPanel's, where I have a database of email addresses, and where they should forward to, and I set a catch-all to pipe to my script.

I have completed this script, however, I would like to make the "To:" field in the header show the address it was sent to, rather than who is was being delivered to. For example, the email was sent to user001@mydomain.com, and the script forwards it to me@gmail.com. How can I make PHP send mail to me@gmail.com, but still show user001@mydomain.com in the headers, like cPanel does?

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you set any headers at all? Or are you using just the default mail() function?

Comment: I'm setting To, From, CC, Date, and Content-Type. I also tried setting To, as per PIM's answer, but it didn't work :(

Comment: I tried BCCing too, but that means that the message comes back to the server, since the "to" is still @mydomain. I could add a X-Processed header, but it seems inefficient to process every message twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the headers of the mail function:

```
$to = 'me@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Testing';
$message = 'This is a test';
$headers .= 'To: User001 <user001@mydomain.com>, User002 <user002@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Email Script <me@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Dosn't work. That makes them both show in the To headers (2 To headers are in the email)